Google Sheets 'Image in Cell' when converting to xlsx
So google sheets 'Image in Cell' option is awesome for organizing and stuff, but when I convert my sheet to xlsx and download it, it comes out of the cell and is larger (opening in numbers or microsoft excel)
Do xlsx documents just not support this?
Or is there a different formatting I need to use?


Cannot reproduce your issue.  When saving a Google Sheet using File, Download, Excel Spreadsheet I see exactly the same outcome in the Google Sheet and in the Excel sheet - https://i.sstatic.net/QsF4hWSn.png

Hey, just updated my post with an image as well. This is what I mean. Same steps, file -> download -> microsoft excel (xlsx)

Do xlsx documents just not support this? Not sure why this question would be asked. What testing have you done for "image in cell" in excel and what were results?

Thanks @Tedinoz SUPER helpful response. I have tried to convert multiple google sheets to xlsx fomat and this always happens with the 'image in cell' pictures, if you try to share->email->microsoft excel, those images don't even appear in the xlsx file sent out. My understanding is that google sheets has different formatting for these images that isn't respected by excel.

No offence was intended. I read "Do xlsx documents just not support this?" as asking whether Excel natively supports "image in cell". I apologise for my mistake. My understanding is that Google Sheets has different formatting for these images that isn't respected by excel Perhaps; I'm more inclined to think that it was just a "bridge too far" for Google; either way, the result is the same. Excel supports "image in cell" and "image in sheet". However when a Google Sheet containing an "image in cell" is converted to Excel, then the image becomes "image in sheet" rather than "image in cell".

@Michal Is the image in excel free floating or is it bound to a cell boundaries(say within A1)?
